# Enable link button in gridview from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

The item template in my gridview contains a textbox and a linkbutton. Im trying to enable a link button in my gridview onblur event of textbox from code behind as follows.

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur", "EnableSaveLinkButton('" + lnkSave.ClientID + "')");
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Width="50px" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
 &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" runat="server" CssClass="mediumFont" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Save" Enabled="false">Save</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


function EnableSaveLinkButton(lnkbtnsave){
    jQuery('#' + lnkbtnsave).attr('disabled', '');
//            jQuery("#" + lnkbtnsave).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

I tried both ways but didn't work. Can anyone suggest how to do it correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: The function name you're adding to txtBox (`EnableLinkButton`) doesn't match the function you've defined (`EnableSaveLinkButton`)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `lnkbtnSave` the name of the link control?

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur", "EnableLinkButton('" + lnkbtnSave.ClientID + "')");
```

Instead of setting `disabled` to empty you must remove the `disabled` attribute.

```
jQuery('#' + lnkbtnsave).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I tried jQuery('#' + lnkbtnsave).removeAttr('disabled') but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: do a view source on the page/html, what is the id of that link?

Answer (score 0):

$('#' + lnkbtnsave).removeAttr("disabled"); should work. The question is, are you calling it at the right time? For example did you ensure that the DOM is ready before calling it? Like this:

```
function EnableSaveLinkButton(lnkbtnsave){
$('#'+ lnkbtnsave).removeAttr("disabled");
};
```

and please replace this in code behind

```
lnkbtnSave.Attributes.Add("onblur", "EnableLinkButton(this);");
```

Comment: How this function call is related to `$()`?

Comment: You are passing textbox object, not LinkButton id.

Comment: Okay but pass txtBox id in enableSaveLinkButton() function by owner..now i have to updated it so what would you say it will work or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function EnableSaveLinkButton(lnkbtnsave){
    var id = lnkbtnsave.id.toString();
    var i = id.split("_");
    index = i[2].toString();
    document.getElementById('lnkbtnSave' + index).disabled='true';
    }
```

Comment: `lnkbtnSave` is inside `GridView` cell, so this will work only for the first element of the grid provided that the linkbutton have the attribute `ClientIdMode = "static"`

Comment: It didn't work. In the page source, the element has a class attribute with value "aspNetDisabled". Does that need to be changed somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can give  your text box and link button  css classes.And then create a disabled inline  style

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" cssClass="txt" Width="50px" MaxLength="5">   </asp:TextBox>
 &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" runat="server" CssClass="mediumFont lnk disabled" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Save">Save</asp:LinkButton>

  <style type="text/css">
    .disabled {
        color: grey;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.lnk').on('click', function (e) {

            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
                e.preventDefault();

            }
            else {

                window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                jQuery('.lnk').removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.txt').on('blur', function () {
            jQuery('.lnk').removeClass('disabled');

        });
    });

    </script>
```

I have compiled a working example for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aex06flfd6ud54e/WebApplication13.zip).Tweak it to your needs.